# Lowering the Meta Participation Threshold

Tags: discussion, meta, announcements, reputation

The reputation threshold for GenAI Meta has been lowered to 1. This will allow all users to participate in the site's meta.

After some discussion with the Community Stakeholders group, we decided that the previous threshold was a possible barrier for users accessing the site's meta to get pointers on improving their questions or participating in the site's meta-discussion.

Given the unique situation, this site is in, and that many of its community members might be newer to the Stack Exchange network and the standard norms of what it takes to write good questions and answers, we wanted to lower the barrier to participation in the meta site to welcome them. By lowering the reputation threshold, we hope to encourage more users to ask questions on best practices and participate in discussions about site governance.

**TL;DR We want to give everyone the opportunity to participate in the site's meta.**

Comment: I think this is a good idea. I wonder if lowering the vote threshold, both up and down, ***on meta*** might also be a good experiment.

Comment: The idea of allowing people with rep 1 participate on Meta sites is still interesting. I didn't think it was necessary, because people don't tend to even know about Meta until they've participated (usually quite substantially) on the main site. However, it's not impossible for people to know about, and be interested in Meta without participating on the Main site ([related, but not the same](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1383/16670)). On this site though, it looks like [not a single person with less than 101 rep has participated on Meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMFhH.png).