# Do we want to review our engagement / participation evolution as community?

Tags: discussion, statistics, participation

A few days ago it was asked if GenAI should volunteer to participate on an experiment. I answered that GenAI doesn't qualify because the CM team was looking for established sites and GenAI is very young.

[image: Site statistics]

- `questions 138`
- `answers 200`
- `answered 75%`
- `users  2.2k`
- `questions/day 1.1`
- `site age 2m`

I mentioned that, in my opinion, the number of questions and the average number of questions by day were low, as at that time the average of questions by day in the last two weeks was 1.1.

Today, Sunday 8th, October 2023, the average daily questions in the last two weeks have dropped to 0.7, but the other metrics have increased a bit.

[image: Site Statistics Sun 8 Oct]

- `questions 145`
- `answers 208`
- `answered 77%`
- `users  2.3k`
- `questions/day 0.7`
- `site age 3m`

In my cited answer, I also mentioned that GenAI has already lowered the reputation required to participate in Meta and that a few days ago it was posted [Initial Moderator Election: Community Interest Check](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/185/12).

I wonder if as a community collaborative effort, we want to periodically review the evolution of community engagement / participation.

Besides the numbers shown on https://stackexchange.com/sites we might start looking at the Users page of the site and Meta, the reputation leagues. If there is interest we might discuss looking at Stack Exchange Data Explorer and other possibilities.

Related

- [Lowering the Meta Participation Threshold](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/181/12)

Resources

- Sites page at Stack Exchange archive on Way Back Machine

  - [2023 Calendar](http://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list)
    This page shows the dates having log records. Blue means that the page was successfully archived, and green means that there as server response that prevented the page from being archived, like a redirect. Since GenAI was launched, there is only one archive for https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list, on October 2, 2023.

Comment: Not only is the number of new questions low, but many of them are on-topic on other SE sites: [What kind of questions are on-topic here but not already on-topic on AI.SE, DataScience.SE or Stats.SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/76/109)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The fact that many questions on GenAI are on-topic on other sites too is interesting. I'm not sure that they meet the rules of the other sites. Please elaborate on an answer (explain why the "but").  P.S. The same happens on other sites, i.e., questions about MacOS, are on-topic in *Super User*, and *Ask Different* questions about Ubuntu, are on-topic in *Super User*, *Ask Ubuntu* and *Unix & Linux*. Spreadsheet formulas are on-topic in *Super User* and *Stack Overflow*, if they are about using online spreadsheet might also be on topic in *Web Applications SE*.

Comment: What is the intent of this question? I only see benefits to review the website, so the answer is “yes”. Then what actions should be taken given the results?

Comment: @A.L If there is consensus that we, the GenAI community want to review the evolution, I believe several community members should participate in making these reviews and the actions derived from them happen. The actions could be collaboratively set a goal and work to achieve it, like setting a minimum of 3 average questions / day every in the last two weeks. We might start by adding an answer with a table to log the stats from https://stackexhange.com/sites

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder if as a community collaborative effort, we want to periodically review the evolution of community engagement / participation.

I agree that having a periodically review of the site's stats is beneficial for the community. The current stats, IMO, shows that the site is not in its healthy period. It could be better; it could be worse.

We have done so many things to push it this far. If there is anything we have not done yet in order to push it again, we should do it now. At least, give it another try. The worst something could happen is the site gets closed, which is quite disheartening considering what we have achieved from a small group of people.

However, I am interested more in the actions after we review it. I suggest that every time we review it, we should take some actions to make the situation better. For example, Wicket (kind of) reviewed current stats like so:

> I mentioned that, in my opinion, the number of questions and the average number of questions by day were low, as at that time the average of questions by day in the last two weeks was 1.1.
>
> Today, Sunday 8th, October 2023, the average daily questions in the last two weeks have dropped to 0.7, but the other metrics have increased a bit.

This means that the *average questions per day* is decreasing over time. We should take some actions to remedy the problem. As a normal user, I can only hope that we have an easy way to boost engagement/participation of the site so that people come and ask questions more but, sadly, I do not have the means to do so.

I expect the SO staff to help us boost the site yet again by some ways like advertising it in other sites in the network, or even feature it so that more people see it. This whole project has been an exception and so special that it created its own way to where it is now. Another premium boosts wouldn't hurt it too much. We already know its worst case scenario. At least, we could try and hope for its best case scenario before it is too late.

Comment: It might be worth noticing that we could post [tag:feature-request] for actions that require certain CM / Staff intervention. For another kind of action that [tag:feature-request] might not be appropriate, a [tag:discussion] might work as a starting point, but I think that for the following three months, we should make an effort to consolidate a group that participates constructively in Meta or the GenAI chatroom every week.

Comment: We have started a bit of a social campaign to tweet about the GenAI site; once it's completed I can report back to Meta with more concrete numbers on how that panned out.

Answer (score 3):

##### About questions/day average in the last two weeks

This metric is not logged in SEDE, and it's not returned by the Stack Exchange API directly.

Some metrics like questions, answers, and users are absolute numbers that might be taken from different sources but vary depending on the date and time they will be retrieved / logged. When logging metrics, it's important to log the source and the date. If a calculation is done, it's also important to report how it was done.

##### Internet Archive: Wayback Machine

In the meantime, we, the GenAI, decide how the review will be done; below is a table with data published at https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#newest taken from archived in the Wayback Machine.

| Date | questions | answers | answered | users | questions/day | site age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [23-10-02](https://web.archive.org/web/20231002003925/https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list) | 141 | 206 | 78% | 2.3k | 0.9 | 3m |
| [23-10-17](https://web.archive.org/web/20231017230824/stackexchange.com/sites?view=list) | 154 | 217 | 75% | 2.4k | 1.0 | 3m |
| [23-10-19](https://web.archive.org/web/20231019225947/https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#newest) | 154 | 217 | 78% | 2.4k | 1.1 | 3m |

There are several ways that a page might be archived on the Internet Archive Wayback Machine.

One action that we could do collaboratively is to look at the above table if it has been passed one week since the last time a capture was done,

1. Do a new capture.
2. Update the above table.

The simplest way to a new capture / archive a web page is to use **Save Page Now**. Just write / paste the URL into the **Save Page Now** field, then click **Save Page**. This will show a page with several options. Click **Save Page**.

**Save Page Now** can be found in

- https://archive.org

  - Click the web button on the toolbar. This will open a menu including the **Save Page Now** form.
- https://archive.org/web
- https://web.archive.org/

Comment: 1 November 2023: 155 questions, 220 answers, 25k users and 0.6 questions/day.

Answer (score 2):

> "I wonder if as a community collaborative effort, we want to periodically review the evolution of community engagement / participation."

Monitoring community engagement and participation are crucial for new sites, and I do these regularly for all new sites (and even established sites).

[`stackexchange.com/sites`](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) shows so much data about site activity, and Area51 and SEDE do this too. On Beta sites other than GenAI, we are [constantly reminded of the site's stats on the home page of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSA2c.png). All of these things are testaments to the fact that site stats are interesting to many people, and that we are not discouraged from monitoring them. In Area51 we are even told whether or not our site's stats are "good" or "excellent" or "need work".

As for GenAI, it is one of the worst sites in the history of SE in terms of its activity at 3 months of age, and this is despite the topic being one of the biggest (if not *the* biggest) areas of hype this year. Sites used to get closed if they didn't have enough activity within their first 90 days, and GenAI would fall in that category. My opinion is that we actually build a GenAI community that "deserves" a site of its own by A51 standards, or we close this site and migrate the questions appropriately to sites such as AI.SE, Stats.SE, etc. (this has been done before, when sites were closed).

Comment: and is probably among the most supported by the company among newly released sites, given they used ad space on SO to promote it directly, included it in many blog articles, talked about it on podcasts, released it at a developer convention that had a heavy lean toward AI, and then further promoted it with the Labs campaign.